# <el-select> how to do multiple select with list stings

Tags: vue.js, vuex, element-ui

use element-ui

now when type " **2** " and press enter, selected " option 2 "

i do need when type " **1 2 4** " and press enter, select "option 1 option 2 option 4"

any ideas

```js
var Main = {
    data() {
      return {
        options: [{
          value: '1',
          label: 'Option1'
        }, {
          value: '2',
          label: 'Option2'
        }, {
          value: '3',
          label: 'Option3'
        }, {
          value: '4',
          label: 'Option4'
        }, {
          value: '5',
          label: 'Option5'
        }],
        value: ''
      }
    }
  }
var Ctor = Vue.extend(Main)
new Ctor().$mount('#app')
```

```css
@import url("//unpkg.com/element-ui@2.11.0/lib/theme-chalk/index.css");
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/element-ui@2.11.0/lib/index.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<template>
  <el-select v-model="value" multiple filterable default-first-option placeholder="Select">
    <el-option
      v-for="item in options"
      :key="item.value"
      :label="item.label"
      :value="item.value">
    </el-option>
  </el-select>
</template>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you searching for something like [this](https://vue-multiselect.js.org/)?

Comment: no, need when type like (1, 3, 5 or 1 3 5 ) and press enter automatic select option 1 & option 3 & option 5
thx for help

Comment: I guess, you have to build that on your own. Just explode the search string via regex by searching for digits and search for them in the option-set by iterating through every label. Or if the digit is unique, then go for the value.